# Parsing predicate logic in bison c++

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, bison

I am developing a software to simplify a formula in [predicate logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) notation, applying some logical laws to output the formula in a **conjunctive normal form**. *I will try to explain everything as clearly as possible.* I know that this is not a mathematic site, but I have to explain a bit some concepts to get concret answers.

---

### What will the software do?

The software will have an entry in which the user can insert a formula and the program will process until reach its conjunctive normal form. So I have to do a parser that can handle the input and put each token in some structure an then thansform it as needed. I will use the following tools:

- C++.
- Qt framework.
- Bison and Flex.

### How to get the [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) of a formula?

- `F=!(a && b)`, then the output will be `F[cnf]=!a || !b` (applying [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).
- `F=(a && b)`, then the output will be `F[cnf]=a && b` (the same, because the input is already in this form).
- `F=a && (b || c)`, then `F[cnf]= (a || b) && (a || c)` ([distributive law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity)).

So, basically is the same formula but separated by the `&&` token.

### Construction status

The first problem that I had when I was trying to manipulate the parts of the input formula was handle the recursion my grammar rules.

Suppose the following rules:

```
expr:
         SYMBOL                                  { cout << " 0 "; }
    |    LEFT_PARENTHESES expr RIGHT_PARENTESES  { cout << " 1 "; }
    |    expr AND expr                           { cout << " 2 "; }
;
```

and the input `(a && b)` then the program prints: `0 - 0 - 1 - 2`, this is: from the last rule executed to the first. I've realize that using a `queue` and inserting each token with the `push_back()` method, then I can get all my tokens ordered by these rules. But I want to operate with these expressions, not only verify her syntax and print the tokens, so I had to create a more complex structure (*not so complex*), a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) to simulate an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and then transform it. Suppose now the formula `a && b || c`, represented in my tree it will be:

```
      &&
     /  \
    a    ||
        /  \
       b    c
```

this is, the parent is always an operator, and the childs are the operands or some expressions. If I have an expression like `a && (b || c)`, then I have to include the parentheses:

```
      &&
     /  \
    a    (
          \
          ||
         /  \
        b    c
```

in that way, all the tokens in the right side of `(` will be enclosed in one group. So, I can do it with *simple formulas*(binary or multiple operations with the `not`, `and`, `||` and `()` operators; I can resolve nested formulas too and apply De Morgan's laws) and this works very good :D.

### So, whats the problem?

Ok, as I say above, it only works with simple formulas. But what happen if the input have the operators `->` (implies) or `<->` (if and only if)? (...) the program does't work. All I have to do is apply the definitions of that logic operators:

- `P->Q`: `!P || Q` (1)
- `P<->Q`: `(P->Q) && (Q->P)`: `(!P || Q) && (!Q || P)` (2)

So, the first thing I have to do is to transform the `->` and `<->` operations using the rules (1) and (2). Once I have all the expressions with the elementals operators (`&&`, `||`, `!` and `()`), I have to distribute the `!` operators using De Morgan's laws and distibute the `||` to returns its conjunctive normal form. It sounds simple to do, but it is not (at least not for me).

Do you remember when I mentioned that the rules are not executed in the order of arrival of tokens?. In this case, I can apply the `->` operator: let `a->b` adding a `!` in the left expression (`a`) and inserting `||` between these two expressions (`a` and `b`). I can do this adding a parent in my tree (`!`), a right child `a`, a `||` parent and another child `b`:

```
      ||
     /  \
    !    b
     \   
      a
```

So, in this case works, but I can't do the same with the `<->` operator!

So, my question is: how I can solve these problems?, do you recommend using another structure to store tokens?, do you know any techniques to do this?

---

### The code

*parser.y*

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include "parsingtree.h"

    using namespace std;

    #define YYSTYPE string

    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);

    ParsingTree tree;
%}

%token  LEFT_PAR
        RIGHT_PAR
        SYMBOL
        END
        NOT
        DIST

%left   AND
        OR
        THEN
        IFF

%start input

%%

input:
        /* empty */
    |   input expr
;

expr:
        SYMBOL {
            $$ = $1;
            cout << "ACA ENTRO A LA REGLA 0" << endl;
            tree.pushSymbol($1);
        }
    |   LEFT_PAR expr RIGHT_PAR {
            $$ = $2;
            tree.pushLogicOperator("()");
        }
    |   NOT expr {
            $$ = $2;
            tree.pushLogicOperator("!");
        }
    |   DIST expr RIGHT_PAR {
            $$ = $2;
            tree.pushLogicOperator("!");
        }
    |   expr AND expr {
            tree.pushLogicOperator("&&");
        }
    |   expr OR expr {
            tree.pushLogicOperator("||");
        }
    |   expr THEN expr {
            tree.pushLogicOperator("||");
            tree.pushLogicOperator("!");
        }
;

            tree.pushLogicOperator("||");
            tree.pushLogicOperator("!");

        }
    |   SYMBOL THEN expr {
            tree.pushSymbol($1);
            tree.pushLogicOperator("||");
            tree.pushLogicOperator("!");
        }
%%

void yyerror(char *s) {

}
```

*scanner.l*

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include "parser.tab.c"
    using namespace std;
%}

%%

[a-zA-Z0-9<>=]+  {
    yylval = strdup(yytext);
    return SYMBOL;
}

"&&" {
    return AND;
}

"||" {
    return OR;
}

"!" {
    return NOT;
}

"!(" {
    return DIST;
}

[ \0\0] {
    return END;
}

"("     {
    return LEFT_PAR;
}

")"     {
    return RIGHT_PAR;
}

"->"    {
    return THEN;
}

"<->"   {
    return IFF;
}

%%
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "parsingtree.h"
#include "lex.yy.c"

typedef yy_buffer_state *YY_BUFFER_STATE;
extern int yyparse();
extern YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(char *, size_t);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    yy_scan_string("(a&&(d->g))->(b&&c)\0\0");
    yyparse();

    tree.printTree();
}
```

*parsingtree.h*

```
#ifndef PARSINGTREE_H
#define PARSINGTREE_H
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ParsingTree
{
public:
    ParsingTree();
    void pushSymbol(string data);
    void pushLogicOperator(string data);
    void printTree();

private:
    struct treeNode
    {
        string data;
        treeNode* leftNode;
        treeNode* rightNode;
    };
    QList<treeNode*> auxList; //guarda el arbol en formación
    treeNode* tree; //pedir el ultimo elemento de la lista, ese es el arbol

    void printTree(treeNode* rTree);
    string latest(treeNode* rTree);
};

#endif // PARSINGTREE_H
```

*parsingtree.cpp*

```
#include "parsingtree.h"

ParsingTree::ParsingTree()
{
    tree= NULL;
}

void ParsingTree::pushSymbol(string data)
{
    treeNode* node = new treeNode;
    node->data = data;
    node->leftNode = NULL;
    node->rightNode= NULL;
    auxList.push_back(node);
}

void ParsingTree::pushLogicOperator(string data)
{
    //binarios
    if ((data == "||") || (data == "&&"))
    {
         treeNode* node = new treeNode;
         node->data = data;
         node->rightNode=auxList.last();
         auxList.removeLast();
         node->leftNode=auxList.last();
         auxList.removeLast();
         auxList.push_back(node);
    }
    //unarios
    if ((data == "!") || (data == "()"))
    {
        treeNode* node = new treeNode;
        node->data = data;
        node->rightNode=auxList.last();
        auxList.removeLast();
        node->leftNode= NULL;
        auxList.push_back(node);
    }
}

void ParsingTree::printTree()
{
    tree = auxList.last();
    printTree(tree);
}

void ParsingTree::printTree(ParsingTree::treeNode* rTree)
{
    if (rTree != NULL)
    {

        printTree(rTree->leftNode);
        if (rTree->data == "()")
        {
            cout << "$(";
            printTree(rTree->rightNode);
            cout << ")$";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << rTree->data + " ";
            printTree(rTree->rightNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks! :D

*PS: if I wrote something wrong or there is something that you can not understand, please ask me so I can express myself better; My English is very poor (I'm from Argentina) and I find this problem very difficult to explain, so I hope you've understood.*

Comment: This is way too long.  Looks like you actually have a couple of questions in there (though my ADD wouldn't let me get but so far into the text).  And the code really needs to be boiled down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You mentioned a lot of time that rules are not executed in the correct order. Well, I would work on that to ease my life afterwards. E.g. left recursion is your friend: if you write something like `exprComp = exprComp operator symbol` an expression `a op b op c` is built in the right order. Combine that with specific classes for each operator and let Bison generate a set on nested objects for the operators of the evaluated expression. On the resulting object you can call a transformation function (`virtual` function in superclass of operator classes?) which recursively build the final form.

Comment: `F=a && (b || c), then F[cnf]= (a || b) && (a || c)` This rule evaluates to false when `(a, b, c) = (1, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pseudocode:

```
P and Q are atomic OR expr between last ')' and corresponding '('

while '<=>' occurs
    P <=> Q |= (P => Q) && (Q => P)

while '=>' occurs
    P => Q |= !P || Q

while '!(P || Q)' || '!(P && Q)' occurs
    apply De Morgan

while 'P || (Q && R)' || '(Q & R) || P' occurs
    |= (P || Q) && (P || R)

apply these rules after each wile:
while 'P || (Q || R)' || '(P || Q) || R' occurs
    |= P || Q || R
while 'P && (Q && R)' || '(P && Q) && R' occurs
    |= P && Q && R
```

You can implement using regex replacement or parsing the string using c++. Be sure to parse from left to right or right to left in a consistent manner. This will determine whether the logic is left or right associative.

Please let me know if you find an ambiguity in this replacement scheme.